# How to check if the user has internet connection in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, cross-browser

I need to condition which function will be called based on internet connection in a React App, for example:

```
if (connected) {
   call function Y()
} else if (!connected) {
   call function X()
}
```

How could I do that? I've tried it with `NetInfo` and with `navigator.online`, but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Aren't you looking for something, like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine)?

Comment: As I said, I tried this, but when I console both `navigator.online` and `window.navigator.online` I get `undefined`

Comment: Just to make sure, didn't you mess with casing (i.e. it has to be `onLine`, not  `online`)

Comment: You're correct, I did messed up with it. It works now. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MDN docs on navigator.onLine:

If the browser **doesn't support** `navigator.onLine` it will always come out as **false/undefined**.

> To see changes in the network state, use addEventListener to listen
> for the events on window.online and window.offline, as in the
> following example:
>
> ```
> window.addEventListener('offline', function(e) {
> console.log('offline'); });
>
> window.addEventListener('online', function(e) { console.log('online');
> });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Browsers implement navigator.online property differently.

In Chrome and Safari, if the browser is not able to connect to a local area network (LAN) or a router, it is offline; all other conditions return true.

In Firefox and Internet Explorer, switching the browser to offline mode sends a false value. Until Firefox 41, all other conditions return a true value; testing actual behavior on Nightly 68 on Windows shows that it only looks for LAN connection like Chrome and Safari giving false positives.

I Would suggest listening to the online event and if you get True then to double sure make an ajax request to any public domain like google or your own

[Based On][1]
[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine